# Linux Mint Login Fail

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa with the cinnamon desktop. Linux Mint has been working fine for me for quite a while, but recently after trying to login to my user account, with the correct password, it quickly flashes these messages:

```
**[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'etc/lsb-release'
* speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
*VirtualBox Additions disabled, not in Virtual Machine
saned disabled: edit /etc/default/saned
*Restoring resolver state. . .**
```

I don't know what this means or how to fix this, but if anyone can tell me, please do because I have a lot of valuable data on my computer and I can't access it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the message flashes and then you can just continue to do your work normally? Or it throws you out? Or the machine hangs? What happens if you login on the console as root? With that or booted from CD have you checked the state of the filesystem (as you value your data you of course have a recent backup)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do all of the messages say `/etc/…`, or is it really a mixture of `/etc/…` and `etc/…` (without the initial `/`) as you have indicated?  More importantly, what are you doing with VirtualBox?  Is the problem on your host machine or a guest VM?  Do you have (or can you obtain or produce) a bootable CD/DVD or USB device (or ISO image) that would let you access your files?  Finally, please verify that my edit didn't do any damage; i.e., are the asterisks part of the messages, or were you trying to make it bold?

Comment: @Anthon It flashes the message and then takes me back to the login screen, for me to enter the password again, then it flashes the screen and continues the cycle.

Comment: @Scott my bad they all say /etc/... And I am not using a virtual machine, so I have no idea what that part is trying to say. I still have the ISO file I used to install it on USB; are u saying I can use that to access the files and then maybe transport them somewhere else and then reinstall linux mint and then put the data back onto that. And what was inside the ** double asterisks is what flashes on my screen quickly, and then it just takes me back to the login screen.

Comment: What happens when you log in at a text virtual terminal?  Press <Ctl><Alt><F2> to get a terminal and login there.  Even if it doesn't allow you to log in, it might display the error messages for long enough for you to be able to read them all.

Comment: @garethTheRed It correctly logged me in that way, I was able to get into the terminal, thanks, is there a way to get to the normal GUI interface from there?

Comment: Probably, but it would be best to fix the issue instead of working around it.  This could down to permissions on your home directory.  While you're logged in, create a test user with `sudo useradd -mg sudo <name of test user>` followed by `sudo passwd <name of test user>`.  Then try to log-in again with this new user, first on the virtual terminal (to check it works) then with the GUI login.

Comment: @garethTheRed I created the test user successfully and was able to login through the virtual terminal, but the gui login gave me the same error as through my normal account :'(

Comment: While logged in at the virtual terminal (either account), type `startx`.  If it fails, hopefully it'll show you some useful error messages. `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` may also help.

Comment: @garethTheRed startx failed as well. What do I do with /var/log/Xorg.0.log?

Comment: @garethTheRed ok I'm gonna call it quits. I am familiar enough with the terminal to be able copy all my files onto a USB flash drive through it. Then I'll just reinstall Linux Mint using my ISO flash drive and put my files back onto it using the other drive.

Comment: @GarrettDelaney Some bootable devices (optical discs, flash drives, etc.) are installers only; this seems to be typical for Windows (although repair disks are an exception). Some simply let you boot an operating system from the media and run it on a computer (they can be a great way to break into a computer, since they bypass all the security in the resident (installed) OS); these are sometimes called “Live CDs”. Some are both, giving you the option of installing or just running the OS that they contain. I was suggesting that, if you had a “Live”-type device, you could … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … bypass the broken login screen and get at your files — but if you have gotten in with Ctrl+Alt+F2 and you can work with that (i.e., you don’t need a GUI), then you should probably stick with that. Next, I was going to suggest trying to diagnose the problem — I would guess that something bad got added to `/etc/profile`, an `rc` file, or something like that. You might learn something that way, and you might even be able to teach the Super User community something that we don’t already know. But, if you’d rather just extract your files and rebuild your system, that’s up to you.